# How to recover PIP

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

I think I uninstalled pip by mistake ^^
I ran something like "pip uninstall pip" in CMD and it completely broke, giving fatal errors.

I uninstalled and reinstalled python, added the correct folders back to PATH, but now it's only working via python -m pip XXXX and not by typing pip XXXX...

If I type pip XXX i get an empty row and CMD gives me back the cursor.
How can I recover? I liked pip XXX better and I am sure that the pip folder is in PATH.

Comment: So the [installation instructions for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) didn't work for you?

Comment: pip is installed, but PIP xxx is answering a blank line

Answer (score 1):

It would help greatly to know what version of each you are using and what OS but for a generic answer...

You could try to install it manually:

Vist:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html

Download:
**get-pip.py**

```
python get-pip.py
```

Make sure your python version matches your pip version. Otherwise you will always have to be specific on your installs. And for sake of simplicity make sure it works fine with just one version of Python installed. Then if that works you can consider having more.

After installing it, if you upgrade your python version make sure you keep it up to date.

I would try something like:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

As os version 21.3.1, you can install `pip` with the one-liner:
`python -m ensurepip --upgrade`.

See [installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) of `pip` doc for details.